# gclib issue with cast

Tags: c, casting, posix

I found this out when writing a test program. I was wondering where this problem is located. Is it in the the C libs (printf), the clang compiler or Mac processor? I compiled this program using clang on a Mac. Here is the short program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int num = 12;
    double temp = 0.0;

    temp = num/10.0;
    printf("%lf\n", temp);
    temp = temp - 1.0;
    printf("%lf\n", temp);
    temp = temp * 10.0;
    printf("%lf\n", temp);
    int new_num = temp;
    printf("%d\n", new_num);
    int cast_num =(int)temp;
    printf("%d\n", cast_num);

    return 0;
}
```

This program works for all numbers except when num ends in 12. When num ends with a 12. new_num and cast num are = 1 and not 2 as it should. if you set num to 22, new_num and cast_num = 2 as it should. Even works as expected if num = 11,10,13,14, etc... it does not work when num ends in 12. So set num = 212, and replace line 10 with temp=temp-21. and the incorrect results happen. Change num to 213 and it works as expected.

Does anyone know the nature of this problem?Odd that it only shows up with a number ending in 12.

Any thoughts?

Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: [Broken floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/3545273) strikes again! Unsure whether a true duplicate, but the answers are fully relevant...

Comment: Thanks for the link. Very informative. Greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of rounding issues. 2.000000 is not always 2!

Try the following:

```
temp = temp * 10.0;
printf("%.20lf\n", temp);
```

and you will probably observe, that temp is *slightly* below 2. So a cast to int will round it down to 1.

The problem is, that already `1.2` (`12/10.0`) cannot be represented exact as floating point number, so already the first division is not exactly 1.2 but a bit less. This error propagates down until your cast. To fix this, round mathematically correct with `round()` for example before casting it to int.

Comment: So, it is a two's complement issue of representing a floating point number. I believe that is what you are referring to? Not all sets of floating point numbers can be represented with two's complement.

Comment: No, floating point numbers are usually represented according to IEEE 754

Comment: Thanks for the response.